# Exadata exachk.sh

Tags: oracle, exadata

I would like to run `exachk.sh` on regular basis.
Now I have to interact with the script and answer all kinds of password questions before the script starts to extract Exadata information.

I want to automate this and I am looking for ways of doing this.
Do I really need to modify the `exachk.sh` script? The problem with this is that this script is fairly often updated on metalink.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can run `exachk.sh -s`
To get it work you have to setup first the SSH user equivalence for database users.

You can find here more infos: [Run the Exachk Tool Automatically on Exadata](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e27420/pichk.htm#sthref2)